# Async Data Reading/Parsing Performance

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, io, monogame

I'm writing code to load and parse text for data in a game. There are a lot of branching reader calls - for example, a map will contain data like props and enemies, and those objects have their own files that are called and read in. This usually all gets loaded quickly, **around 1.5 seconds**, but on slower machines it can take around **5+ seconds** and cause the game window to become non-responsive until it's done.

Right now I'm looking into ways to keep the window active while still keeping load times short. I've separated some of the loading into Tasks that run in the background of the main thread, and then when the loading is done it tells the main thread to switch states and the game continues. This works, however, I've gone from a  **1.5** second loading time to a **53** second loading time. Is this normal performance when switching to a background task like this? I've posted some generalized code as an example of how it's currently being handled.

```
Map map = null;
//Main Update Loop
public void Update()
{
    if(GameState == Active)
       map.Update();
    else
       ShowLoadingScreen();
}

//LoadWorld gets called from elsewhere, like a UI
public async void LoadWorld()
{
   GameState = State.Loading;
   await Task.Run(() => { LoadFile("mapdata", out map); });
   GameState = State.Active;
   map.Start();
}

//This loads the file and reads the first line
//which tells the reader what sort of object it is
public void LoadFile(String file, out Map m)
{
   m = new Map(); //create new map
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);
   String line;
   Object obj = null;
   while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
   {
      switch(line)
      {
         case "A":
           obj = parseObjectA(line, sr); //continues with its own loop
           break;
         case "B":
           obj = parseObjectB(line, sr); //continues with its own loop
           break;
      }
      map.addObject(obj);
   }
}

//This loops through the reader and fills an object with data, then returns it
public Object parseObjectA(String line, StreamReader sr)
{
   Object obj = new Object();
   while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
   {
      String element;
      String value;
      //parseLine is a function that breaks apart the line into an element and value
      parseLine(line, out element, out value);
      switch(element)
      {
         case "name":
            obj.Name = value;
            break;
         case "position":
            {
               int pos = 0;
               Int32.TryParse(value, out pos);
               obj.position = pos;
               break;
            }
      }
   }
   return obj;
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you could use the `async` methods from your `StreamReader` in the `LoadFile` method. Consider also wrapping the usage of your stream reader in a `using` block. I'm continuing to read to see if there's anything else that might affect performance.

Comment: @Fabulous From what I was previously told, ReadLine doesn't block threads since it's an I/O operation and ReadLineAsync could possibly decrease performance even more since the actual reading doesn't need to be done asynchronously, so using ReadLineAsync would add unnecessary overhead. Is any of that true?

Comment: If you are doing some significant processing of the data you get back, the difference might be negligible. Consider [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a47412ed-1b21-45c2-8554-cc602d6b5ddb/is-streamreaderreadlineasync-much-slower-than-readline?forum=parallelextensions) where that concern is addressed. Ther are other aspects to the question there but your question is addressed. Typically `async/await` calls cascade all the way down the call stack. In this case, you might want to look at the code in your `parseLine` operation.

Comment: @Fabulous parseLine just splits the string into values I can use in the switch. So if the line looks like "name" "Joe", I'll get 'name' back as the element and 'Joe' back as the value. I didn't think it was important to add in the code example.

Comment: Typically how many lines do you process when loading the file(s)? Is it possible to process the lines in parallel; if one line isn't directly affected by another you might want to look into that. Without the ability to run the code it won't be possible to pinpoint the exact cause. It's possible you may benefit from parallelization.

Comment: @Fabulous I would say maybe somewhere between 12k to 16k lines get processed. I think in some cases, some objects can definitely have their properties set in tandem, like in the example I gave. In most cases, however, different lines definitely effect how the others would behave, so those parts couldn't run parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I would post this as a comment but I'm not yet allowed, so expanding it into a fuller explanation.

From a game development perspective, I would create the loader as a backgroundworker thread.  This will leave the main thread/form of the window responding to user input.

Within the backgroundWorker you can then fire off indivdual tasks to do individual workloads as you need it, but the UI is always responsive.

The important thing to remember is to create your needed variables in the root of the class, then populate them in the Background thread.  Doing this means you can then easily read the results once everything is completed in the main thread.

As an example:

```
class MainThread
{
    BackgroundLoader bgLoader;

    public MainThread()
    {
        bgLoader = new BackgroundLoader();
    }

    public void LoadItems()
    {
        bgLoader.Load();
    }
}

class BackgroundLoader
{
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    // create the variables to hold the results.
    Map map;

    public void Load()
    {
        backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += BackgroundWorker_DoWork;
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        while (!backgroundWorker.IsBusy) { }
    }

    private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // This is where you do the work and load your variables, which you then access once the thread is complete.
        map = LoadMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure this solves my problem but it's definitely worth looking into.

Comment: As you were experiencing slowdowns with Tasks when running them from the main thread, you could try running the whole load stack single threaded as you were, but entirely in a background thread. This may remove the issues you are seeing.